# Migrating AccountStore from Xamarin app to MAUI app

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I have an old app built using Xamarin, and I'm creating a new version of the app built using MAUI.

I've seen examples of how to migrate AccountStore settings from my old app to a Xamarin Forms app using Xamarin.Auth.(https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/wiki/Migrating-from-AccountStore-to-Xamarin.Essentials-SecureStorage#migration--helper-class)

I haven't seen any way to migrate from AccountStore to MAUI. Does the same method work?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. The previous one was about not being able to retrieve AccountStore settings on an Android device using Xamarin Forms. Now I'm attempting to go from Xamarin Forms to MAUI and was wondering if it's even possible to access AccountStore settings in MAUI.

Comment: Your link mentions xamarin essentials SecureStorage. Search for maui SecureStorage doc. Adapt link instructions as needed.

Comment: You can Upgrade a Xamarin.Forms app to .NET MAUI with the [.NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/upgrade-assistant) and Maui also has the [Secure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=android) you can refer to this link for more information.